# Xtext crossreferencing no longer working?

Tags: xtext

I have used Xtext for many years, and have always been able to cross-reference from one grammar to another grammar. But today, on Eclipse Photon, the usual method no longer works.

In the same workspace, I create two Xtext projects, using default options, `org.xtext.example.adsl.ADsl`

```
grammar org.xtext.example.adsl.ADsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate aDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/adsl/ADsl"

AModel:
    agreetings+=AGreeting*;

AGreeting:
    'AHello' name=ID '!';
```

and `org.xtext.example.bdsl.BDsl`,

```
grammar org.xtext.example.bdsl.BDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate bDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/bdsl/BDsl"


//import "http://www.xtext.org/example/adsl/ADsl" as adsl

ModelB:
    bgreetings+=BGreeting*;

BGreeting:
    'BHello' name=ID '!';
```

where `BDsl` would like to import `ADsl` via the commented-out import statement `import "http://www.xtext.org/example/adsl/ADsl" as adsl` for use in cross-referencing.

In the past, before uncommenting that import, I would have to add a resource reference `referencedResource = "../org.xtext.example.adsl/model/generated/ADsl.genmodel"` to `GenerateBDsl.mwe2`.

```
module org.xtext.example.bdsl.GenerateBDsl

import org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.*
import org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.model.project.*

var rootPath = ".."

Workflow {

    component = XtextGenerator {
        configuration = {
            project = StandardProjectConfig {
                baseName = "org.xtext.example.bdsl"
                rootPath = rootPath
                runtimeTest = {
                    enabled = true
                }
                eclipsePlugin = {
                    enabled = true
                }
                eclipsePluginTest = {
                    enabled = true
                }
                createEclipseMetaData = true
            }
            code = {
                encoding = "UTF-8"
                lineDelimiter = "\n"
                fileHeader = "/*\n * generated by Xtext \${version}\n */"
            }
        }
        language = StandardLanguage {
            name = "org.xtext.example.bdsl.BDsl"


            referencedResource = "../org.xtext.example.adsl/model/generated/ADsl.genmodel"


            fileExtensions = "bdsl"

            serializer = {
                generateStub = false
            }
            validator = {
                // composedCheck = "org.eclipse.xtext.validation.NamesAreUniqueValidator"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I generate the Xtext artifacts for `BDsl`, I now get the following error (the import still commented out).

```
434  [main] ERROR xt.generator.XtextGeneratorLanguage  - Error loading 'ADsl.ecore'
```

The genmodel is certainly being found, since a completely different error is generated if the file cannot be found.

What is going on?

- Am I making some stupid error?
- Is this related to [this bug](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core/issues/41)? If so, is there a work around?

*[... I am aware that the example contains no actual cross-references. I have purposely induced the error in the simplest possible manner. ...]*

Comment: can you provide the complete source code? ususally you reference other stuff by "platform:/resource/project/model/Some.genmodel"

Comment: @Christian Dietrich Thank you. That was the problem. Replacing with [referencedResource = "platform:/resource/org.xtext.example.adsl/model/generated/ADsl.genmodel"] solves the problem. Kicking myself. Just double checking (with code) that this solution works with Gradle parent project style. Above is a simple Eclipse build structure without nested projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you refer to the referenced genmodel in a way that it actually can be insolved. the ususal reference would look like `platform:/resource/project/model/Some.genmodel` so in your case `referencedResource = "platform:/resource/org.xtext.example.adsl/model/generated/ADsl.genmodel"`

Comment: Thank you. I am still battling to make this work with the Gradle build, which creates a parent project and nested subprojects. In this case [referencedResource = "platform:/resource/org.xtext.example2.adsl.parent/org.xtext.example2.adsl/model/generated/ADsl.genmodel"] nor [referencedResource = "platform:/resource/org.xtext.example2.adsl/model/generated/ADsl.genmodel"] work, both yielding unmapped path errors. Infact, this was how I ended up trying "../". I will post a new question targeting the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the dependencies in Gradle are correct and the genmodel file and ecore are packaged to the jar of dsl a

Comment: For now, I must go back to using the Eclipse build because it is working for me.

Comment: Thank you for Xtext. It is one of the truly powerful tools in a programmer's toolbox.

Comment: again make sure you simply package the genmodel to the jar. if you create a new project with 2.14 this should already happen. org.xtext.example.mydsl.parent/gradle/source-layout.gradle

Comment: I have it all building with Gradle out the box. Thank you so much! Just to note that one must still use [referencedResource = "platform:/resource/org.xtext.example.adsl/model/generated/ADsl.genmodel"] and not [referencedResource = "platform:/resource/org.xtext.example.ads.parent/org.xtext.example.adsl/model/generated/ADsl.genmodel"]

Comment: It breaks if one choose the Web integration option. If one does not choose web integration then everything is as above and I would have got it correct first time. Select web integration, however, and the file is no longer on the path.

Comment: Simply compare the gradle files and see that is different.

Comment: btw i cannot reproduce that. in my web project the genmodel is part of the jar